# Good object structure for selective composition without class explosion

Tags: java, php, oop

My real scenario is a bit hard to explain so I'll map it to a more recognizable domain, say home entertainment equipment:

A particular piece of equipment can offer different services:

A Panasonic XYZ can play DVDs and CDs.
A Sony ABC can only play CDs.
A Hitachi PQR can play DVDs and receive TV.
...
...

Each service (DVD, CD, TV,...) has a default implementation which most models use, but some models have customized versions of particular services.

**Interfaces**

Models choosing to implement DVD'izable, CD'izable, TV'izable,... contracts would 
result in a lot of code duplication between models.

**Single Inheritance**

A single superclass implementing the default services would allow me to have a single subclass for each model containing all of its custom behaviour. My superclass would however be quite unwieldy and heavier than it need be for models that don't offer all types of services.

**Multiple Inheritance**

Multiple inheritance with its ability to selectively incorporate the services required and provide default implementations, on the surface seems ideal. I value the cohesiveness of having all PanasonicXYZ's custom functionality in a single class more than the coupling introduced by the inheritance.

But I'm not using C++ (rather PHP) and I sort of feel there's a better way anyway. Nor do I want to use proprietary extensions like mixins or 5.4's traits. 

**Composition**

I see a class explosion with my custom functionality for a particular model scattered over multiple classes--I'd need a PanasonicXYZ_CD class and PanasonicXYZ_DVD class for example, and they'd only ever be used by the PanasonicXYZ object.

Is there a preferable structure?

**Edit:** I'll have a good think about some of the comments and answers made instead of prematurely commenting.

Comment: Using your example, I might call those `Device`s and `Function`s. If you fully map out all of the objects (`Device`s) and all of the `Function`s for each device, you will probably discover that you're really just needing a usable data structure. Once you get the right data structure for your requirements, you should be able to keep your class structure relatively flat and confined. But you need to have a full accounting first, I think. Build your model, then your classes. Don't forget to validate your model with as many subject-matter experts as possible.

Comment: CD functionality for instance would expose quite a few methods, maybe skipTrack(), ripAsMp3(),... ripAsMp3() might differ between different models' CD players. I see how your comment applies if CD functionality was just a group of properties but maybe I'm not getting what you are saying.

Comment: It all has to do with what you are doing with your clases. Are you planning to actually replicate each device's functionality in methods? What is the ultimate objective of your application?

Comment: The objective is to retrieve data from a database, have it processed by a multitude of external service providers with varying interfaces and both common and unique capabilities and ultimately generate reports.

Answer (score 3):

**Use composition Luke**:

Object classes represents a *role* in your system. Even when is natural to think about a "Device", for OOP purposes is better to think about what are the roles of your device: DVD Player, TV Receiver, CD Player, etc.

It doesn't matter that a single device does all of them, thinking in the roles that the object is going to have will help you to end with **single responsibility** objects:

```
class SonyTvWithDVDPlayer {
     DVDPlayer asDVDPlayer();
     Tv asTv();
}
```

In that way is easy to refactor common functionality, you can have a `GenericDVDPlayer` and return that in the `asDVDPlayer` method.

If you want to allow a more dynamic usage, like asking to a `Device` which functionality it supports, you can use a kind of [Product Trader](http://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=product%20trader%20pattern%20riehle&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.33.2026&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=y2sDT8LKCNSutweoh5nJBQ&usg=AFQjCNGTc8BV4UoEN7HTKr2b8fAwM0M8xw), for example:

```
interface  MultifunctionDevice {
      <T> T as(Class<T> functionalitySpec) throws UnsupportedFunctionalityException
}
```

and them in the code you could do something like this:

```
device.as(DVDPlayer.class).play(dvd);
```

See that in this case the "multifunction device" acts like a *Product Trader* and the `DVDPlayer.class` is the *spec* of the *product*.

There are a lot of different ways to implement the trader and the spec, one is to use the *Visitor* pattern. But I found that in a lot of cases (when you want to be able to configure your "multifunction devices" dynamically) you can do something like this:

```
class MultifunctionDevice {
      Iterable<Device> devices;

      <T extends Device> T as(Class<T> spec) {
          for (Device dev : devices) {
              if (dev.provides(spec)) return dev;
          }
          throw new UnsupportedFunctionalityException(spec);
      }
 }
```

This combined with a Builder and a *fluent API* makes easy to define different devices without class explosion:

```
   dvdAndTv = new DeviceBuilder("Sony All in one TV and DVD")
        .addPart(new SonyDvdPlayer())
        .addPart(new SonyTv())
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use dependency injection to do something like this:

```
abstract class Device {
    private function addFunction(Function $function)
    {
        // store it
    }
    public function callFunction($function, $method)
    {
        // check whether local method exists (e.g. $function$method() or dvdPlay())
        // if not: call $function->$method
    }
}
```

Then all devices extend `Devices`, all functions extend `Function`. To change a default `Function` implementation, your device class (e.g. SonyAbc) could provide its own methods for e.g. `dvdPlay()`.

Comment: That was the first thought that popped in my head reading the question, but I couldn't decide if it was appropriate or not.

Comment: Me neither. But given the information on top, it should work and avoid too many classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would favour Composition.

Do you even need actual Classes for each Device? Or would it be sufficient to provide a specific TV as a properly wired instance of a Device with some Features?

```
samsunSxYZ() {
   Device device = new Device()
   device.addFunction(new SamsungDvdStandard())
   device.addFunction(new SamsungCdStandard())
   return device;
}

samsunSabc() {
   Device device = new Device()
   device.addFunction(new SamsungDvdStandard())
   device.addFunction(new SamsungCdSpecialAbc())
   return device;
}
```

Features could be retrieved by invoking

```
DvdFeature dvdFeature = device.getFunction(DvdFeature.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the services already known and limited in number?
If so I would do something like this :

- Define an interface for each kind of service (e.g. DvdPlayer, TvReceiver, CdPlayer, etc...)
- Give each service interface a default implementation (the common one that many devices will share) and code whichever model-specific implementations you also need.
- Define a second set of interfaces to denote that a particular device has the capability to offer a service (e.g. DvdPlayerCapable), each interface declaring one (uniquely-named) getter for the service interface, for example:

  ```
  public DvdPlayer getDvdPlayer();
  ```
- Now your device can combine multiple capability interfaces, and use either the default implementation of the service or a model-specific one...

And so if for instance you want to go to dvd chapter 15 on your Sony123Device, which is a *DvdPlayerCapable*, you can call:

```
mySonyDevice.getDvdPlayer().goToChapter(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two problems.  The first problem is how do you pass around common functionality between services, that can be solved via inheritance. Something like the following:

```
public abstract class BaseDevice  
{  
  //common methods with implementations  
}  

public class SonyPlayer extends BaseDevice {...}  

public class SamsungPlayer extends BaseDevice{...}
```

The interesting piece of the problem is where we get into customized versions of the defaults.  In this instance we would not want to use inheritance because we know it directly violates LSP.  So we could approach it via composition which would result in something similar to the following:

```
public class CustomSonyPlayer  
{  
   SonyPlayer sonyPlayer;  

   //Adds a digital signature after using the SonyPlayer#ripMP3
   public void ripMP3Special(CustomSonyPlayer customSonyPlayer)  
   {  
          MP3 mp3 = sonyPlayer.ripMP3(new MP3("Life goes on"));  
          customSonyPlayer.addSignature(mp3);
   }  
}
```

Or you could expose the **common** special functionality inside of utility class.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have provided a generic Custom_Fuctions on my root abstract class. It is serialized for storage

I then call

```
foreach($device->Custom_Functions() as $name=>$function){
    if(is_int($name))
        echo '<li>',$function, '</li>';
    else
        echo '<li>',$name, ': ', $function, '</li>';
}
```

add customs via method:

```
function Add_Custom($name, $function) {
    if(empty($name))
        $this->customizes[] = $function;
    else
        $this->customize[$name] = $function;
}
```